# Turning a background image into a link with CSS

Tags: html, css

I know there are similar questions but they don't exactly answer my problem. Am trying something really simple, turning a background image into a link, am following a tutorial and he did it easily so i tried it but it just didn't work, the image just doesn't show, i did all my checks from the tutorial but it just doesn't work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="s017.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CSS</h1>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="fb"></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="tw"></a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com" id="ig"></a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com" id="in"></a>
    <a href="http://www.snapchat.com" id="sc"></a>
    <a href="http://www.whatsapp.com" id="wa"></a>
</body>
</html>

body{
font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
}

#fb/*, #tw, #sc, #in, #ig, #wa*/{
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}

#fb {
background-image: url('image03.png');
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

as for the result:
[image: result of my code]

as you can see there is nothing in there other than the  title
i taught it was the browser but i tried it with Mozilla and Chrome with same result.

Comment: adblocker active? errors on console (f12 on most browsers)?

Comment: is your "image03.png" in the same folder as your index.html?

Comment: i tried it without adblock, same problem, and i can't find any errors on consol

Comment: yes my image is in the same folder

Comment: are you trying to create little thumbnails of each image with this?

Comment: yes, am folowing along this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cf3eiHRvVug&index=56&list=PLwLsbqvBlImHG5yeUCXJ1aqNMgUKi1NK3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use this as thumbnails, I recommend just using images instead of trying to set background images. When you are setting the background image, it isn't resizing the image, but showing a small 60x60px section of the image in the background. If the top left corner is white, that's what you are seeing. Instead of background image, try this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
  <img id="fb" src="http://blog.addthiscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-facebook.png">
</a>
```

Here's a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-hitchcock/pen/vazXEQ) showing what I believe you are looking for. If this isn't exactly it, or there's a reason specifically you must use background image, let me know and i'll update my answer to reflect.

Comment: there isn't really a reason that i want to use background image, am just following along the tutorial and it was weird to me that my code didn't work while being, from what i could see, correct. and no, the image isn't so small that it's showing a white section, because i even tried it with other images that have no white, with same result

Comment: the code you gave is giving basically the same result as the tutorial, but i would really appreciate it if i could find my mistake or why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Try in your #fb section adding in
    background-size:60px 60px;
see if that changes anything for you. If not try inspecting and see if it shows that it is trying to load the image. Better yet, try the answer markup I sent you and see if it loads the image or gives a broken image thumbnail. It could be as simple as having the wrong href src.

Comment: the image isn't inside a folder is it?

Comment: no it is not, it's right there in the same folder as index.html, with the right name "image03.png". i could screen it if you want :)

Comment: you see the tutorial is about using image sprites, where instead of loading 5 separate images, you have one image that has all different logos for example and you resize it with CSS, it's for performance i guess but I'll try what and see the result

Comment: you know what you are actually right, i tried height: 200px;
width: 200px; and it showed my a bit of the image. which is weird because when i tried it with another image that is 60px 60px it didn't display it, anyways thank you so much for your help

Comment: Happy it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

At first please be sure that your link for CSS file is working , As you know you should put your Style codes in  **s017.css** file that is in your html file folder.
Probably your image size is big and didnt fit in your 60*60 (a) tag block or your image have a white space in left top position that you intered.For the first you can use background-size in css for " #fb " :

```
background-size:contain;
```

and for the 2nd probability you should crop your image with paint or other image editors.Of course,you can set the position in center of image but this is not recommended.
I hope this work for you!
Have fun !!

Comment: the problem was with the fact that the image is too big. thanks for your suggestions